# Array.from() strange behavior with parseInt()

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

So I am trying to convert an array of strings to an array of numbers using the following code.

```js
let a = ["0", "0"];
let b = Array.from(a, parseInt);
console.log(b);
```

and what I get is

```
b = [0, NaN];
```

I am familiar with a similar issue using `Array.map()` since it provides three arguments to `parseInt()` and the second argument (index) is interpreted as a radix by `parseInt()`. But it shouldn't be the case for `Array.from()`.

Can someone give me an explanation please?

Comment: it is just the same approach of `map` with the second parameter of `Array.from`.

Comment: This happens because the callback function (in thi case, parseInt) is invoked with two arguments, which are the current value and the index of the value in the original array. Considering what said, parseInt is invoked with two arguments and, in parseInt, the second argument is the radix: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt hence the callback in the second item is invoked with value `'0'` and radix `1`, yielding `NaN`

Comment: Ok, the MDN documentation doesn't specify the callback signature. But that it is the same as using `map()` is mentioned later in the text.

Comment: Change this `Array.from(a, parseInt);` for this `Array.from(a, ([n]) => parseInt(n));` this way, you're avoiding the problem with the implicit param `radix` you're passing through the index from function `Array.from(...)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to have the actual function, not a reference:

```js
let a = ["0", "0"];
let b = Array.from(a, e => parseInt(e));

console.log(b);
```

The issue is that using `map` (which is what the second argument of `Array.from` is) passes three arguments to the callback - the current item (what you want), the index (unnecessary), and the array (unnecessary). All three of these get applied to `parseInt` - so it looks like this:

```
let b = Array.from(a, (item, index, arr) => parseInt(item, index, arr));
```

Unfortunately, `parseInt` uses the second argument as the base of the number it produces (as in, decimal is base 10, binary is base 2, octal is base 8, hexadecimal is base 16). And the second argument passed is the index. So it's attempting to parse `0` to a number in base 1, which doesn't exist.

You could also just use the `Number` constructor.

```js
let a = ["0", "0"];
let b = Array.from(a, Number);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: this seems to work. I was trying to avoid lambda functions. Is a description of an actual function and a reference somewhere nicely explained.

Comment: You should explain what happens with the second param (radix) which is the origin of the problem.

Comment: Well I wrote in the question I know the issue with the radix argument. I didn't know `Array.from()` works the same way as `Array.map()`

Comment: Edited @Ele, could you (and others) please remove your downvotes?

Comment: It's done!! `(:`